# PHP login check or redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I am trying to create a check login or if the user is logged in it will redirect user to the home page. Right now the problem is that it forces user to the login_forum.php page, but when I try to login, it just resets the form and does not redirect to home.php page.

home.php

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) 
{

header ("Location: login_form.php");

}

else
{
header ("Location: home.php");
}


?>
```

Is there something wrong with this? What file would have the problem with it?

checkuser.php

```
if($login_check > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
$$key = stripslashes( $val );
}
// Register some session variables!
session_register('first_name');
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
session_register('last_name');
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
session_register('email_address');
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
session_register('phone_number');
$_SESSION['phone_number'] = $phone_number;
session_register('address');
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;

mysql_query("UPDATE abnc_users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

header("Location: home.php");
```

I have been researching and could this be a problem?

login_form.php

```
<form action="checkuser.php" method="post" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to also set `$_SESSION['login']`... Example:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = 1;
```